# running keras model.predict on dataset returns different accuracy than model.evaluate on same dataset

Tags: keras

I'm training this neural network with loan data to predict the status of a loan. When I train the model and evaluate it, I get an accuracy of ~98%. However, if I try to individually predict each loan status, and then cross compare to the actual loan status, then my "success rate" (the number of predicted loans that were actually right) falls to around ~94%. I'm curious why this is happening, since evaluate uses predict in its inner workings right?

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: You might want to look at the batch size. While evaluating, you might set a large batch size, whilst during prediction, you calculate on single images. Try to set `batch_size=1` during evaluation.

Comment: and please include some code (a minimum amount, so that anyone can understand your problem better)

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply but the reason why it was different is because I was using binary cross entropy instead of categorical cross entropy for my loss function! Dumb mistake that's all